# How do I align new table rows added using JS with existing table rows?

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, userscripts

The table rows I added are the top 2 (MAT235 and CSC263). If it helps, I can also post the HTML code of the bottom 2 rows and of the top 2 rows.

[image]

This is how I added table rows/data:

```
var tableRef = document.getElementsByClassName('section academic-history xs-block-table')[0].getElementsByTagName('tbody')[1];

var newRow = tableRef.insertRow(1);

var newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);

newCell.innerHTML = 'MAT235Y1'
```

and this is what the existing rows' HTML looks like

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="course in session.courses" class="courses">
    <td>STA257H1</td>
    <td>Probability and Stat I</td>
    <td class="course-weight">0.50</td>
</tr>
```

And this is the new rows' HTML generated by my JS code above.

```
<tr>
   <td>MAT235Y1</td>
   <td>Calculus</td>
   <td>1.00</td>
</tr>
```

EDIT: @wOxxOm's comment fixed it for me.

Comment: Use devtools to inspect the elements and find the difference between your inserted cells and the other ones. There's probably an attribute or a class name or an additional cell.

Comment: Apparently you should copy the attributes e.g. newRow.className = 'courses', similarly for the third cell.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for the suggestion, I was going to try that and will do so now. I had assumed "data-ng-repeat" was the culprit behind the difference in formatting and had been trying to see how I could set that for my new table rows.

Comment: @wOxxOm it worked! Thanks a lot, I didn't expect adding a class name to fix it.

Comment: I'm glad you worked it out. Please either provide and accept an answer or close your question.

Answer (score 0):

By the request of @isherwood, I am providing an answer I received from @wOxxOm.
The solution is to copy the class name attribute (newRow.className = 'courses') for the new rows.